# Parameter from <a href></a> to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<ul>` `<li>` menu. When the `<a>` element inside the `<li>` is clicked, I need to run a Javascript function and this function needs some parameters like id or name. How can I do it? How can i send/retrieve parameters?

Example Javascript:

```
function addTab(title, uri) {
    var tabNameExists = false;
    $('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i) {
         if (this.text == title) {
             tabNameExists = true;
         }
    });
```

Example HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">W to set parameters</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="url" onClick="addTab(this);">link</a>


function addTab(this)
{
    $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr('name');
}
```

Comment: perfect, I ended up using "data-" and $(this).data('id'), tks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="url" id="someUniqueID" title="SomeTitle" onClick = "addTab(this.title, this.href,this.id);" >link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are not quite related to your question, anyway, here is the way:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="some_js_function(id,name)">W to set parameters</a></li>
```

More logics can be made, depends on how you write `some_js_function(id,name)`.

Note: If you want to fetch the attribute of the `<a>` or `<li>` tag , you can go with @PSR's answer.